# Java Play - how to make a simple form with 2 fields and send values to Controler?

Tags: java, html, forms, playframework

I have a simple route '/firstlast' and I want to display web page 'firstlast.scala.html' with 2 fields and submit button.

How to call that 'firstlast.scala.html' file from a route?

And how to transfer values entered in a form to some controler (some method)?

Comment: FYI I've created an issue on Play Framework's Github because I think this area needs better documentation: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/8004

Comment: Great! Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display the file, you make a controller and call the controller from the routes file. The methods in the controller will call the template.

You'll want to make two controller methods one to handle a `GET` request and one to handle a `POST` request.

[Routing `GET` and `POST` requests to controllers](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaRouting)

[How to inject a template into a controller and call it](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaTemplatesDependencyInjection#Dependency-Injection-with-Templates)

The `GET` request is called first. It shows the form with empty values. For the `GET` the controller makes an empty form model object and passes the form to the template.

[How to put default values into the form object on the GET request](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaForms#Filling-a-form-with-initial-default-values)

When the user submits the form it sends a `POST` request. The controller for the `POST` request validates the request body and either process it or, if there's an error, passes it to the template.

[How to validate the form on a `POST` request](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaForms#Handling-binding-failure)